Numpy fails for unclear reason
I am calling Numpy in my subroutine:
import numpy as np

def IsUnderLine(xarray, yarray, TestPoint):

    a = np.array([0, 50])
    b = np.array([0, 193.53])
    coefficients = np.polyfit(a, b, 1)
    coefficients = np.polyfit(xarray, yarray, 1)

    # calculate the Y of the point which should be on the line
    YOnLine = TestPoint[0] * coefficients[0] + coefficients[1]

    # Check if our real Y is over or under the line -> which way is the circle?
    if (TestPoint[1] > YOnLine):
        return True
    else:
        return False


bb = IsUnderLine([1,2], [3,4], [3,5])

print(bb)

If I call 'IsUnderLine' from the test code in the same file, it works fine. But when I call the function from an outside routine, it fails without explanation at the first test assignemtn to the variable a. The call to the routine is:
      if (IsUnderLine([p1, p3], [z1, z3], [p2, z2])):
and all the values in the arrays are float.
The error I get is:

  File "C:\Users\rainer.bars\PycharmProjects\mapcircles\IsUnderLine.py", line 8, in IsUnderLine
    a = np.array([0, 50])
        ^^
  File "_pydevd_bundle\\pydevd_pep_669_tracing_cython.pyx", line 460, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_pep_669_tracing_cython.PyLineCallback.__call__
  File "_pydevd_bundle\\pydevd_pep_669_tracing_cython.pyx", line 452, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_pep_669_tracing_cython.PyLineCallback.__call__
AttributeError: 'PyLineCallback' object has no attribute 'py_db'

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

What is the problem, why do I get an error in one case but not the other? And how do I fix the error?
